# How can I make a regular expression that contains special characters, like word boundaries, with a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I am trying to write a regular expression that will match a word that is contained in a variable, but only when the word is a whole word. I wanted to do this by using word boundaries, like this:

```
var data = 'In this example of data, word has to be replaced by suggestion, but newword must not be replaced';
var item = {word: 'exampleWord', suggestion: 'suggestion'}
var word = "\b"+item.word+"\b";
var suggestion = item.suggestion;
var re = new RegExp(word, "gi");
data = data.replace(re, suggestion);
```

However, constructing a regular expression in this fashion apparently does not work. Can anyone suggest a way to construct this regular expression containing the variable and the word boundaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use double escaped `\\b`:

```
var word = "\\b"+item.word+"\\b";
```

In case your `item.word` may contain special characters, use the [RegExp.escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) function.

```js
var word = "PRICE: $56.23"
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
alert("\\b"+RegExp.escape(word)+"\\b");
```

Comment: Do I use the RexExp.escape on word (so var word = "\\b"+RegExp.escape(item.word)+"\\b";) or in the new RegExp (new RegExp(RexExp.escap(word), "gi");)?

Comment: @Eva: I added a sample snippet.